# Stefan Boltzmann law and absorptivity

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, heat-conduction

I have this really big confusion , and it is about the Stefan Boltzmann law

Does this law works for absorption?
Or is it only radiation

I have seen my textbook replacing emissivity with absorptivity to find the rate at which energy is absorbed. However I don’t see any correlation
This equation caused the trouble(equation to din the net radiation rate ). [*Also Assumption a=e*, a is the absorptivity ]
$$dq/dt=eA\sigma(T1^4-T2^4)$$

(Also a proof will be really helpful)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Stefan Boltzmann law will tell you how much heat a blackbody will absorb from another blackbody.

Your equation is giving the net heat flowing from body 1 to body 2.

To break it apart a little and relate this to absorption.

Body 1 is **emitting** $e A \sigma T_1^4$ to body 2 and **absorbing** $e A \sigma T_2^4$ from body 2. Hence the net heat flow body 1 emits is the difference between these fluxes $e A \sigma T_1^4 - e A \sigma T_2^4 = e A \sigma \left( T_1^4 - T_2^4 \right)$ which is the equation you stated.

Regarding the absorption aspect of you question.

The main axiom regarding a blackbody is that it is a perfect absorber. So any radiation falling on it is absorbed and contributes to raising the temperature of the blackbody.

In your example, you are considering a blackbody with an emissivity/absorptivity. This is the factor of incident radiation which is absorbed, via Kirchoff’s law, it also reduces the emission rate of the body. Sometimes a non-ideal blackbody is called a grey body.

Comment: How did u find the rate of absorption

Comment: My question is how do we calculate rate of absorption from Stefan Boltzmannl aw

Comment: @boyfarell cuz all my books tend to use this equation to find the radiation absorbed but I don’t see any reason why it is supposed to work

Comment: I understand that the net heat flow is  emission - absorption but how did u find the absorption

Comment: That’s the main axiom regarding a blackbody; any radiation hitting it is absorbed. In this case, the body is not perfect but absorbs a fraction proportional to its emissivity/absorptivity.

Comment: but where’s the black body

Comment: We are discussing about a normal body and the surrounding

Comment: I appreciate ur effort thanks , but could u make urself more electorate

Comment: Thanks @boyfarrell

Comment: Are you saying you have the surroundings at temperature $T_2$ and the body at $T_1$? Maybe let’s try the chat feature of the website to discuss more so we understand each other?

Comment: ok sure , can u come after   90  mins?

Comment: First time using the chat... I can available if we can figure it out!

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/122459/discuss-stefan-boltzmann-law-and-absorptivity